# Is there a word for "awesomely extremely useful", used for an idea?

Tags: single-word-requests, science

I'm looking for a synonym of *useful*, with a maximum grateful attitude. It is not a person to be thanked, but an **idea**. It mostly a breakthrough idea, but *breakthrough* is not what I'm looking for. I have found some synonyms of *useful* on Google, but I'm confused how to choose one:

> functional, practical, handy, convenient, utilitarian, serviceable, of use, of service, beneficial, advantageous, helpful, worthwhile, profitable, rewarding, productive, constructive, valuable, fruitful

To get you understand sense of the word, here is an example of it. In theoretical physics, physicists have to deal with tons of mathematics, and physical meanings usually be buried in the lines of <s>code</s> math. For example, the collision of two particles has this mathematical expression (I'm trying to trim a lot of jargons here):

[image: Mathematical Formula]

Feynman the genius found the way to bring the physical meaning back to life:
[image: Feynman Diagram]

Compare to a real world collision:

[image: Event Representation]

What a _______ idea!

<sub>Image and expression taken from the wiki page of [Feynman diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feynman_diagram).</sub>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Revolutionary** might be a good fit

*when used as an adjective, the term **revolutionary** refers to something that has a **major, sudden impact on society or on some aspect of human endeavor**.*

Usually Revolutionary means something that has completely changed the way people perform a type of action, rather than simply modifying or slightly improving it. For example, one could say the invention of the steam engine **revolutionised** transport.

Answer (score 1):

How about "game changer"

From [M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/game%20changer) :

> a newly introduced element or factor that changes an existing situation or activity in a significant way

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Community how were you triggered?